# Android: How to share data between apps

Tags: android

I need some help in making an android application in which the admin can insert data like advertisement or user data and another application users can use to read and rate the data via the internet.

- How do i start?
- Is there a good video tutorial?
- How can I share data between apps / users?

Comment: You can use files.Save and load public cache files. Better way is to make trow a services...

Answer (score 0):

> The Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL) is similar to other
> IDLs: it lets you define the programming interface that both the
> client and service agree upon in order to communicate with each other
> using interprocess communication (IPC).

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl

https://youtu.be/JxmozhBzzcg

You may also need to define a query for Android 11 (API level 30)

```
<manifest package="com.example.game">
  <queries>
    <!-- Specific apps you interact with, eg: -->
    <package android:name="com.example.service" />
  </queries>
  ...
</manifest>
```